# Weird bug in react-native ListView

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-listview

Please read the full question as it may be helpful to know this behavior.

I have a sectioned ListView which contains a list of tasks. The list view has three sections (Recent, Later and Past). Each task can have a list of users who should be informed when a task is done. A task is moved to `Past` section when it is marked as done. When a task is marked as done, below things take place

1. Mark the task as done in the redux store
2. If the task has participants, send a remote notification to the participants

When the task is marked as done, the redux store is updated which triggers a re-render of the `ListView`. The second step happens after the `ListView` has re-rendered according to the logs.

What is happening is that the second step is triggered with the props of a different task and not the task which was marked as done. It is as if the `ListView` items were reused and the `ListView` item which was previously used for the task that is marked done is now reused for some other item and rest of the code is run using the props for that other task which is very weird. Below is how it looks in the code

```
  changeTaskStatus = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(ActionCreators.markTaskDone(this.props.id))

    // A re-render is triggered once the above action is dispatched and the
    // this.props.id in the next step is not the one that the user marked as done
    this.props.dispatch(ActionCreators.notifyParticipants(this.props.id))
  }
```

I will try to create a sample project that exhibits this problem. If you have any information regarding this behavior, please post an answer or a comment.

Comment: I guess that would mean that I would need to store all the `props` in an object and use that object to access the data. It is not very intuitive and kind of breaks the closure behavior for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind data with `ListView` like follow

`<ListView
   ...
   renderRow={this.renderList.bind(this)}
/>`

So when after update list you need to pass `ID` to in function `changeTaskStatus` and update ListView.

And also you can make separate object of `ID` and manage it by your custom logic

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to suggest. The 'renderRow' method is already bound to 'this'. 'changeTaskStatus' method is called when a user clicks on a task and the task list is re-rendered as a result of marking the task as done and the 'this' is pointing to a different object during call to notify participants.

Comment: What I think is when you call this.props.dispatch(ActionCreators.notifyParticipants(this.p‌rops.id)) and you pass this.props.id may be you get ID wrong here so need to check here if you are not getting perfect id here then go with my solution